# Azure function Daprtopictrigger error in K8s "non-retriable error returned from app while processing pub/sub "

Tags: docker, kubernetes, azure-functions, dapr

I have a simple Azure function with DaprTopicTrigger. it works locally but wheen I am deploying to K8s I am getting error. Below is the message signature

```
[FunctionName("TestFn")]
    public static void Run(
        [DaprTopicTrigger("%PubSubName%", Topic = "%TopicName%")] CloudEvent subEvent,
        ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation("C# function processed a PrintTopicMessage request from the Dapr Runtime.");
        log.LogInformation($"Topic B received a message: {subEvent.Data}.");
    }
```

Here is the error that I get when I post a message to Topic:

```
non-retriable error returned from app while processing pub/sub event T1: . status code returned: 404" app_id=*** instance=e*** scope=dapr.runtime type=log ver=1.11.
```

Below is the code for K8s setup

DockerFile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS installer-env

COPY . /src/dotnet-function-app
RUN cd /src/dotnet-function-app && \
mkdir -p /home/site/wwwroot && \
dotnet publish *.csproj --output /home/site/wwwroot


FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/dotnet:4
ENV AzureWebJobsScriptRoot=/home/site/wwwroot \
    AzureFunctionsJobHost__Logging__Console__IsEnabled=true \
    ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://*:3000


 COPY --from=installer-env ["/home/site/wwwroot", "/home/site/wwwroot"]
```

Subscription.yaml

```
apiVersion: dapr.io/v2alpha1
kind: Subscription
metadata:
  name: testfn-sub
spec:
  topic: testtopic
  routes:
    default:  /TestFn
  pubsubname: pubsub
```

Deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: testfn
  labels:
    app: testfn
  annotations:
    reloader.stakater.com/auto: "true"
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: testfn
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: testfn
      annotations:
        dapr.io/enabled: "true"
        dapr.io/app-id: "testfn"
        dapr.io/app-port: "3000"
        dapr.io/enable-api-logging: "true"
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: testfn
        image: image:label
        envFrom:
        - configMapRef:
            name: testfn-cm
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3000
          protocol: TCP
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        resources:
          limits: 
            memory: 128M
            cpu: 200m
          requests:
            memory: 128M
            cpu: 200m
```

Please suggest what I might be doing wrong.